# Laravel Homestead with Vagrant and Hyper-V

Tags: vagrant, homestead, hyper-v

I am trying to get laravel homestead to run under hyper-v as i need hyper-v for a different project.

i can download the box and start the `vagrant up` command without issue; however the command fails with the following:

```
C:\development\Homestead>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'hyperv' provider...
==> homestead-7: Verifying Hyper-V is enabled...
==> homestead-7: Verifying Hyper-V is accessible...
==> homestead-7: Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    homestead-7: Box Provider: hyperv
    homestead-7: Box Version: >= 7.2.1
==> homestead-7: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    homestead-7: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead
==> homestead-7: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v7.2.1) for provider: hyperv
    homestead-7: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/7.2.1/providers/hyperv.box
    homestead-7: Download redirected to host: vagrantcloud-files-production.s3.amazonaws.com
    homestead-7:
==> homestead-7: Successfully added box 'laravel/homestead' (v7.2.1) for 'hyperv'!
==> homestead-7: Importing a Hyper-V instance
    homestead-7: Creating and registering the VM...
An error occurred while executing a PowerShell script. This error
is shown below. Please read the error message and see if this is
a configuration error with your system. If it is not, then please
report a bug.

Script: import_vm.ps1
Error:

Failed to import a virtual machine.

Error Code: 32784
Cause: VM version is unsupported

C:\development\Homestead>vagrant box remove laravel/homestead --provider virtualbox
You requested to remove the box 'laravel/homestead' with provider
'virtualbox'. The box 'laravel/homestead' exists but not with
the provider specified. Please double-check and try again.
```

trying to manually import the VM via hyper-v manager and it states i don't have access to the folder or it doesn't exist. I am running everything in Administrator CMD and cannot see why this would not import.

I am running Win 10 Pro and have done searches which seem to indicate an inability to import VM's from an old config, but according to https://app.vagrantup.com/laravel/boxes/homestead it was updated less than a month ago and supports hyper v fine.

Would greatly appreciate help on this.

I have read other answer similar to my issue but they pertain to timeouts.